# Getting javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException when try to send mail using java

Tags: java, email, exception

I have read and tried all solution given in stackoverflow and in other various sites but still getting issue and getting exception.

Code :

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class sendmail {

Properties emailProperties;
Session mailSession;
MimeMessage emailMessage;

public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {

    sendmail javaEmail = new sendmail();

    javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
    javaEmail.createEmailMessage();
    javaEmail.sendEmail();
}

public void setMailServerProperties() {

    String emailPort = "587";//gmail's smtp port

    emailProperties = System.getProperties();
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

}

public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {
    String[] toEmails = { "emailid@gmail.com" };
    String emailSubject = "Java Email";
    String emailBody = "This is an email sent by JavaMail api.";

    mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
    emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
    }

    emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
    emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
    //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

}

public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String fromUser = "emailid";//just the id alone without @gmail.com
    String fromUserEmailPassword = "test";

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
    transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
}

 }
```

When I debug code , it stop working at line : **Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");**

I have added following JARs :

> Mail.jar , pop3.jar , smtp-1.4.2.jar , Activation.jar , additional.jar

Full exception :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp
>       at javax.mail.Session.getService(Session.java:764)
>       at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:689)
>       at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:632)
>       at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:612)
>       at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:667)
>       at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:154)
>       at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
>       at JannyaPaid_Device.sendmail.sendEmail(sendmail.java:68)
>       at JannyaPaid_Device.sendmail.main(sendmail.java:26)

Also I want to ask that firewall can prevent this things to send mail? As we have some firewall installed but I able to open and send mail thrugh gmail manually.

Comment: `Transport.send(emailMessage)` is enough to send mail why you want to do that way ?

Comment: But if I do like `Transport transport = null;
 
     Transport.send(emailMessage);`  then also getting same exception.

Comment: You are not setting protocol to be used I guess set the below line `emailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");`

Comment: I tried but still getting same exception..:(

Comment: In stacktrace debug I am getting message : org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "username@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Getting same exception :(

Comment: Now getting new error like `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
 class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. bc14sm16722533pac.6 - gsmtp

 at sendmail.main(sendmail.java:45)
Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception:
 class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. bc14sm16722533pac.6 - gsmtp

 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
 
`

Comment: When I debug code , from line `Transport.send(message);` it jumps to `return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password)` and then getting given exception.

Comment: Yes but in debug it is showing me diff. username with label called "defaultusername"

Answer (score 2):

For - Must issue a STARTTLS command(start transport layer security), you might need a certificate in the path(in JDK/JRE) and same on the Email server side as well.